# Usage of mvnvm vs mvn?

Tags: maven

I saw a friend using mvnvm for compiling their projects. What is the advantage of mvnvm over mvn, and what functionality does it provide? 
I could find the website mvnvm.org, but I couldn't find much information beyond that.

Comment: what did your friend say?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm the author of mvnvm, its a script that will download and run the specified (or default) version of maven for your project.

The main benefits are:

- You can control the version of maven used for your project centrally in one place (store it *with* the project)
- You don't need every possible maven version installed on your build agents as mvnvm can be installed and manage whats needed
- If you contribute to a project only occasionally, then you don't need to worry about switching as the source of that project defines the maven version and you can be sure your building it correctly
- The version of maven used to build your release artifact is forever defined in the source, this makes reproducible builds more likely in the future.

Good luck!

Comment: How does the `mvn` command know that the `mvnvm.properties` file exists? Does `mvn` have built-in support for mvnvm now?

Comment: @byxor `mvnvm` provides a `mvn` callable (a bash script) which knows ... if some *real* maven binary is found first by the shell, that `mvn` probably does not.